# Rspec not finding class methods

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing some tests for my backend jobs and I'm having a weird issue with rspec not finding my methods.

I wrote a simple class & test to illustrate the issue :

app/interactors/tmp_test.rb :

```
class TmpTest
  def call
    a = 10
    b = 5
    b.substract_two
    return a + b
  end

  def substract_two
    c = self - 2
    return c
  end
end
```

spec/interactors/tmp_test.rb :

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe TmpTest do
  context 'when doing the substraction' do
    it 'return the correct number' do
      expect(described_class.call).to eq(13)
    end
  end
end
```

output:

```
TmpTest
  when doing the substraction
    return the correct number (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) TmpTest when doing the substraction return the correct number
     Failure/Error: expect(described_class.call).to eq(13)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `call' for TmpTest:Class
     # ./spec/interactors/tmp_test.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00177 seconds (files took 1.93 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/interactors/tmp_test.rb:5 # TmpTest when doing the substraction return the correct number
```

Comment: Please stop editing the original question and revert changes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a class method, it's an instance method. Your test should look like this:

```
describe TmpTest do
  subject(:instance) { described_class.new }

  context 'when doing the subtraction' do
    it 'returns the correct number' do
      expect(instance.call).to eq(13)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing my confusion between class and instance methods, however there still is an issue with the second method, I'll edit my original post.

Comment: This is all cool, but you missed an elephant hunting for flies :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: the `b.subtract_two`? Didn't miss it. It was out of scope of the question :)

Comment: Damn, I looked at the changed version, where it was in the very center of the scope :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete mess. Corrected version with comments:

```
class TmpTest
  def call
    a = 10
    b = 5
    # b.substract_two # why do you call method of this class on b?!
    a + subtract_two(b)
  end

  def substract_two(from)
    from - 2
  end
end
```

Also: don’t use `return` in the very last line of the method.

Comment: indeed my code is very bad quality here, I just wrote it in a hurry to illustrate the issue, 
I can see now that my issue was calling the class method (substract_two) on the wrong element (b)
With your version it works.

Comment: You should accept Sergio’s answer, not mine, since he resolved the issue you were asking about.

Comment: My "real" problem (this code here mimics the code on my app) was actually linked to calling a class method on a wrong element so your answer indeed was the good one for my use case.

Comment: My answer was not by any means good for this particular question as was initially stated. Nobody cares about what your actual problem was. This question deserves Sergio’s answer, that simple. SO is a service for people looking answers on their problems, not for you personally. So please mark Sergio’s answer as correct.